# Webrtc udp protocol specification format webrtc udp to c# udp server unpack received udp data

Tags: javascript, webrtc

How to communication with webrtc udp client to c# udp server
i successfully create webrtc connection. and i got some data from webrtc during createanswer. now how can i unpack that data..
i got data from webrtc : `\00\01\00L!\12\a4B_\ee\d5\11Aqo\e8\d4\87\a5-\00\06\00\11b39246e9:1f25502f\00\00\00\00$\00\04n\7f\00\ff\80)\00\08\f2AK\ff\02\08w\f8\00\08\00\14\8f\03\9fjb~:{\ad\d5\cfD\17@\8d\c9$\fclP\80(\00\04]\f2Sc'.`
i want unpack format...

```
var ip = "127.0.0.1";
port = "6666";
con = new RTCPeerConnection();
server = con.createDataChannel("channel1");
var offer = {
    type: "offer", sdp:"v=0\r\no=mozilla...THIS_IS_SDPARTA-68.0.1 4528709258380120638 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 8A:26:E1:E1:ED:7E:0A:E5:B6:83:2F:2B:59:4B:D3:FF:4E:C7:4F:33:B9:BE:5D:B3:0B:9D:1A:B3:53:F6:D3:D9\r\na=group:BUNDLE 0\r\na=ice-options:trickle\r\na=msid-semantic:WMS *\r\nm=application 9 UDP/DTLS/SCTP webrtc-datachannel\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=candidate:0 1 UDP 2122252543 " + ip + " " + port + " typ host\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=ice-pwd:b7a34c945ff294faa99c3c632a581684\r\na=ice-ufrag:b39246e9\r\na=mid:0\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=sctp-port:5000\r\na=max-message-size:1073741823\r\n"
};

con.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(offer)); 
con.createAnswer(function (answer) {
        con.setLocalDescription(answer);
    },
    function (error) {
    });
```

now i got data from webrtc.. on my plain udp server ( 127.0.0.1 : 6666 )..

Comment: Please do not spam unrelated tags: Java != JavaScript.